# Roundoff error between Visual Basic and Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, node.js, excel, vba

I found a VB script in an Excel file that implements Runge-Kutta integration for solving a differential equation. I converted the implementation line by line to Javscript. However, the Javascript program does not yield the exact same results as the VB one... The numbers are close enough to be marginally acceptable, but I trust that the VB implementation is correct as it was part of a PhD Dissertation. So this leads me to believe that my Javascript implementation, running on NodeJS, suffers from some rounding ghosts.

In particular, I have noticed that as I continually add `0.01` to my time counter, the values are eventually unable to be represented properly, and I get values like `5.299999999999999934` instead of `5.3`. This makes sense to me, as I have read about this quirk of Javascript in some books.

**My Questions Are**

Is my observation correct that Visual Basic does not suffer from this same precision shortcoming?

Does this mean plain vanilla Javascript math is inherently less accurate than plain vanilla VB math? (Without using other math libraries).

If I clamp my time variable, as in, force the value to be 5.30, instead of 5.299999999, will this actually make my results more correct?

edit: Using a `Math.round(X*100)/100` clamp changes the output of all my time values to have only 2 decimal places, but does not actually change the values of any computations.

Comment: JS's math would be less precise, not less accurate if that is the case.

Comment: ^ thanks for the clarification. I tend to always use the wrong word as I'm not a practicing scientist.

Comment: you can multiply by, for example 100, round or +x.toFixed(2), and then divide by 100 to cleanup minor rounding "errors".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript uses IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point numbers...just like Visual Basic.  The only difference is that JavaScript uses doubles for *all* numbers (that is, it doesn't have an integer type, or a single-precision float).

If a calculation in VB uses numbers of type `Double` in its calculations, it should have the same accuracy and precision as the equivalent calculation in JavaScript.

The upshot is that VB is in no way more accurate with respect numerical calculations than JavaScript.  Whenever you're dealing with floating-point values, though, you have to be careful.

You should probably read David Goldberg's excellent article, [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

The chance of errors multiplying is increased with the number of summations, and there are a LOT of summations in techniques like Runge-Kutta, so the algorithm has to be constructed very carefully to take this into account.  The definitive book on the subject is the time-tested [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/aboutNR3book.html), which covers Runge-Kutta, and takes into account floating-point errors.